# Maintaining keyboard control when calling external command in elinks

Tags: linux, bash, framebuffer, mplayer, elinks

Currently, using a method described [here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/18431/youtube-in-mplayer-script/), I am able to stream YouTube videos without using X windows/Flash. My primary text-based browser is elinks, and you can call external programs and pass to it your currently selected link by adding this to your `elinks.conf` file:

```
set document.uri_passing.youtube = 'ytmplay.sh %c'
bind 'main' 'F10' = 'link-external-command'
```

This currently *works*, but unlike calling `ytmplay.sh YOUTUBE_URL' directly from the console, I cannot actually control mplayer, and can only stop the video if I force-terminate mplayer. Does anyone know how I can maintain control of mplayer when calling it through elinks external commands/URI passing?

Comment: `elinks` seems to background `mplayer` and so you have no way to communicate with it, I don't know any easy way to work around this sort of patching `elinks`. Switching to [`youtube-viewer`](http://code.google.com/p/trizen/) might be better option.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `mpv` as it has IPC protocol. I use following script to run YT url with mpv:

```
#!/bin/bash
$(which mpv) --input-ipc-server=/tmp/soc_mpv "$@"
```

Then I can control MPV with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# play
echo '{ "command": ["set", "pause", "no"] }' | socat - /tmp/soc_mpv
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# pause
echo '{ "command": ["set", "pause", "yes"] }' | socat - /tmp/soc_mpv
```